# Modify Magento Order on Submit

Tags: event-observer, magento-community, edit-order

I need to create a module which can allow a user to change the string used on the front end for delivery methods and use existing delivery methods from another module. I've got a decent idea of how to the conversion and everything, but I don't know what observer event I should be using to catch the order once it's been submitted. Does anyone know which one will let me catch the order before it's placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that is dispatch right before Magento saved the order is: `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_before', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
```

You can also use: sales_order_place_before and sales_order_place_after where you know if the order pass payment method.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_before', array('order'=>$this));
```

Using this events, you can set info in the order but you should not execute `$order->save()` because this is executed by Magento system in a transactions.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. Also thanks for the mention about $order->save(), hadn't considered that